# Partition Deleted Switching from Win8 to Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, windows-8, data-recovery

I have freshly switched from Win8 to Ubuntu 13.10 right now.

But to my surprise the whole hard disk is a single partition and I can not see my old data. I used the Option ' remove w8 blah blah blah'.

Some people suggested to use testdisk. I have installed and running the deepsearch right now. found two of the drives. But some other people say not to run it from the same window but either from live cd or usb and then run testdisk.

What are the possible options and solutions in this case.

Comment: Let see if I can understand. You used the option "delete windows 8" and now you can't find window8? If you used that option your disk has been wiped out (it is specified in the blah blah blah). Your best bet is recovering from a backup.

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu, you completely wiped your hard drive. Everything is gone now, unfortunately, unless you have a backup, or you have the time and tools to dig through "empty" bits on your hard drive (unless installing Linux will wipe even the already empty parts of your drive). I suggest trying to go all NSA on your hard drive and recover deleted files, assuming you haven't written over them already. Check out this website: http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/09/recover-deleted-files-in-linux/

Comment: so let me clarify a bit. I was using win8 with 5 partitions. I did not wanted dual boot but a fresh Independent Installation. during installation it automatically detected and give me the auto-selected option 'Erase window 8 and Install Ubuntu 13.10' along with I my self selected ' Use LVM with new Ubuntu Installation' thought this would be the option to select and adjust partitions. I thought this will automatically erase windows 8 and install Ubuntu to drive C: but After successful Installation I saw that I only have one partition C: with no data and every thing is erased.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah like Rmano said, you replaced the partition that held Windows 8 with Ubuntu. Unless you have a backup, that is all gone.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated after OP comments**

If I understood correctly, you had win8 with 5 logical drives (like for ex. C:, D:, E:, F: and G:) and you wanted to install Ubuntu over Windows in c: while keeping your data in the other drives intact? I am not sure.

**However, since your goal is to recover your old data,** you are right about using a data recovery tool, and those people you mention are right about not running them on the same partition.

Every data recovery program must save the recovered data somewhere, and it can't be the same disk on which the old data resides, since it could be overwritten.
It could also be overwritten by memory swapping to disk.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery:

> You should NOT write to the failed device, as it can worsen a hardware failure, and overwrite existant data in case of lost files.
>
> Shut down the affected machine as soon as possible, and restart it from a LiveCD or LiveUSB. Be certain that the "live" cd does not automatically mount any partition or swap space.

They also go on explaining a lot of different solutions, and you really should read it.
One of the tools they suggest is "Ubuntu rescue remix", although not maintained for a while, but there are really plenty of alternatives, most of them [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_recovery_software).